# find closest element from the class

Tags: jquery

I have following jQuery code:

```
<div class="take_vattachment" onclick=""><i class="add"></i> Add </div>
<div class="colorbox white">
   <table class="sort valign-top margin10-top" id="attachment_table">
   <tbody id="take_vattachment"></tbody></table>
</div>
```

I want to find attachment_table id from take_vattachment class.

I wrote the following code to find the same but it won't work.

```
$('.take_vattachment').closest('#attachment_list').length
```

But it gives me length 0. How should I find the class from id.

Comment: `$('.take_vattachment').parent().find('#attachment_list')`

Comment: Ids **must** be unique within the document. You could simply do `$('#attachment_list')`

Comment: I am unable to find `take_attachment` class in your given code.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work. Theoretically the id-s should be unique - practically it works. Anyway, you don't have any `#attachment_list` element, thus you won't find any.

```js
let e = $('.take_vattachment').parent().find('#attachment_table')
console.log(e.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="take_vattachment" onclick=""><i class="add"></i> Add </div>
<div class="colorbox white">
   <table class="sort valign-top margin10-top" id="attachment_table">
   <tbody id="take_vattachment"></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` ***must*** be unique. If it is not, that **must be fixed**.

Comment: It _should_ be. Most of the functions do work without, some not. It is bad practice and might lead to problems. Fortunately, all browsers can handle. When using component models, you might well end with repeated ids and having no way to fix it - because of using third-party code.